# iOS:Unix:Mac extract info from a static lib regarding supported architecture(s). How?

Tags: ios, linux, macos, unix, static-libraries

I have a static library on my Mac and curious to know if the lib was built for armV7s architecture or not? Is any command/tools available to show the supported architectures in this library?

Thank you,
Kamran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use otool for getting that information.

From otool's manpage

> -L     Display the names and version numbers of the shared libraries that the object file uses.  As well as the shared library ID if the
>   file is a
>                 shared library.

Example

```
> otool -L libRaptureXML_universal.a 

Archive : libRaptureXML_universal.a (architecture armv7)
libRaptureXML_universal.a(RXMLElement.o) (architecture armv7):
Archive : libRaptureXML_universal.a (architecture i386)
libRaptureXML_universal.a(RXMLElement.o) (architecture i386):
```

Answer (score 4):

```
your-mac:~ yourlogin$ file /Path/to/somebinary

/Path/to/somebinary: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
/Path/to/somebinary (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Path/to/somebinary (for architecture i386):      Mach-O executable i386
/Path/to/somebinary (for architecture ppc7400):   Mach-O executable ppc
```

Comment: i received the lib from a website, and trying to use it in my Xcode but have some link error that complains it doesn't contain armV7s ...

Answer (score 2):

Not disagreeing with the other answers, but here's one more option:  use the `lipo` command.

[The Apple man pages for lipo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html)

You can run `lipo -info` on executables, or libraries.  Some examples:

```bash
minime:arc username$ lipo -info libarclite_iphonesimulator.a
input file libarclite_iphonesimulator.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libarclite_iphonesimulator.a is architecture: i386

minime:iPhone username$ cd HelloWorld.app/
minime:HelloWorld.app username$ lipo -info HelloWorld
Non-fat file: HelloWorld is architecture: armv7
```

Comment: Guess we found three pretty helpful ways of doing it then :D (+1)