# How to use ldid?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing, jailbreak

I am trying to run unsigned application on iOS 5.1/iPhone 4s (jailbroken). What I did:

1. Disable code signing in XCode.
2. Built unsigned iPhone app.
3. Copied it to my iPhone via SSH to location /User/me/development/HelloWorld.app
4. Now I try to simulate its signing to run this application on iPhone. I run follwing commands:

.

```
cd /User/me/development
chmod -R 777 HelloWorld.app
ldid -S HelloWorld
```

However, I receive following error:

```
util/ldid.cpp(567): _assert(78:arch != NULL)
```

What are possible reason of such error and now to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1)** Using `ldid -S` is the **correct** usage.  Not lowercase (`-s`).

**2)** Usually, when I get this error, it's because I built my app with the wrong architectures.  Most older versions of `ldid` that I've used cannot sign *fat* binaries (but see **Update** below). Fat binaries are ones with more than one architecture inside.  For example, a dual `armv6` and `armv7` executable.  Or with Xcode 4.5, it's probably defaulting to `armv7` and `armv7s`.

In the project build settings, use the **Architectures**,  **Valid Architectures** and **Build Active Architecture Only** settings to determine which architecture executable is built.  For jailbreak development, I usually set **Build Active Architecture Only** to `YES`. And valid archictures set to `armv6` and `armv7`.

**3)** Also, some older versions of `ldid` cannot sign `armv7` executables. If you get the [pre-built copy from KennyTM's site here](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/list), it supports `armv7`.  Note that this `ldid` is built for Mac OS X, so it's designed to be run on the executable on your Mac, after building without signing in Xcode, but *before* you upload to your iPhone.

Newer phones can generally run executables built for older architectures, but not the other way around.  So, build for the oldest architecture you want to support.  You just will lose some optimizations in the newer architectures (which most people don't care too much about ... let me know if your app needs these optimizations, and I'll post more).

So, if you want to support old devices (iPhone < 3GS), I would set **Architectures** to *only* `armv6`, making sure to remove the default setting of `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`.  If you only need support for relatively new ones, then pick `armv7`, but make sure you use a version of `ldid` that can sign `armv7` binaries.

**Edit:** to determine if the executable you were trying to sign was a fat one, run this at the command line:

```bsh
> cd HelloJB.app

> ls
HelloJB     Info.plist  PkgInfo     date.zip    en.lproj

> lipo -info HelloJB 
Non-fat file: HelloJB is architecture: armv7
```

As you can see in the above output, my `HelloJB` executable is not fat, and only has armv7 code.

### Update

I believe that the pre-built version of [ldid found here](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid&can=2&q=) **can** now sign fat executables, although there are still `ldid` versions floating around that cannot.  Also, I think that if you install a recent version of [iOSOpenDev](http://iOSOpenDev.com/), it will give you a version of `ldid` that can sign fat executables (default install location of `/opt/iOSOpenDev/bin/ldid`).

Comment: Thanks, you right, I use mixed architecture armv7/7s, it must be the reason.

Comment: @VASoftOnline, yep.  That's now the default for XCode.  I would just set the architecture to **only** build for `armv7`, and then let `ldid` code sign that non-fat executable.

Comment: My iPod must hate me. I have just this problem and tried this solution to no avail. Even lipo fails: 'dyld: lazy symbol binding failed'

Comment: @spamguy, [there are other ways to check for a fat binary, too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12537617/119114).  Can you try one of those, and see if this is the problem?  Or just look at your Xcode build settings, and see if you're configured to build for only one architecture?

Comment: It turned out to be a moot point; after an extended period of app failure my app started working normally for no reason. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: MyApp.app/MyApp are: armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) 

does it means it is a fat file,right? but with only one architecture?

Comment: @ItayLevin, if it **only** lists `armv7`, then it's not a fat binary.  CPU type and subtype are just two different descriptors, but `armv7` is the only *architecture* I see in what you posted, so it's not fat.

Comment: "cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)" is armv7s. `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info ...` will dump the value properly. A radar exists for `/usr/bin/lipo`'s inability to recognize the processor and architecture.

Comment: I can confirm the updated ldid appears to sign fat binaries. Don't forget to chmod your binary also with execute permissions. Lastly if you don't have a Mac you can accomplish this using Travis CI now as will be seen at https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-iphone shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from what seems Xcode 4.5 onward, maybe as early as 4.4 have not checked, in order to pseudo code sign using the ldid tool, you need to download and install 'Command Line Tools' from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#) or you can download it from within Xcode, Preferences->Downloads

Otherwise you will get errors like

- util/ldid.cpp(584):
- ./minimal/mapping.h(54): _assert(2:false)
- util/ldid.cpp(567)
- and so on

You still need to make sure it is not a "fat" binary and only armv7 as armv6 is no longer supported.

ldid -S ExampleApp

Answer (score 0):

The error assert(2:false) comes from the fact that HelloJB (not HelloJB.app) is write protected!

1. Start Terminal.app
2. Go to directory HelloJB.app
3. chmod +aw HelloJB
4. ldid -S HelloJB works !

Comment: this appears to be a comment (on omar's answer?)... not an answer to this question