# Jailbreak development using xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak

I have been looking around for learning how xcode can be used for jailbreak development.

I have Lion and jailbroken iPhone3G and xcode4.6 which doesnt support iPhone3G.

I have installed `ldid` but have no idea how to use it.

I have to make launch daemons, too, and attach them with my application. I have followed [this](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/) tutorial for making a daemon but i got stuck in the setup for creating an open tool chain template in xcode. I followed every step but my xcode is not showing any template for open tool chain. **Is it really required to have open tool chain template?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right.  Xcode 4.6 doesn't support the iPhone 3G.  Can you install an older version of Xcode?  For example, Xcode 4.4 still supports the 3G.

[Login to the Apple Developer Portal and download old versions here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

You can choose to install the old version of Xcode in a different folder, so that it doesn't overwrite the new version (for example, install to `/Developer-old/` or something).

Once you install the old Xcode version, you can navigate to the installation directory and look for the directory named:

> iPhoneOS5.0.sdk

(or probably iPhoneOS5.1.sdk would work, too).  Then, copy that entire folder into the new Xcode 4.6 installation directory.  For example:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

Afterwards, you should see this:

> iPhoneOS5.0.sdk 
>   iPhoneOS6.1.sdk

With the 5.0 SDK installed, you can now build apps for the iPhone 3G, using Xcode 4.6.  You can also now uninstall Xcode 4.4 if you want. [See more about this in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13061562/119114).  The key is that you will be building your app for `armv6` (only).  Armv6 is the iPhone 3G's processor.

The second step is to turn **off** code-signing within Xcode.  In your project settings, you set the provisioning profile to **Don't Code Sign**.  [You must modify an Xcode configuration file to allow you to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953407/119114).

Now you build the app in Xcode.  When you're done, navigate to the directory on your Mac where the app has been built (where the `MyAppName.app/` folder is).   Then, you use [ldid](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid&can=2&q=) to [fake code sign the app executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12773253/119114):

```
ldid -S MyAppName.app/MyAppName
```

Now, your app has a fake code signature that will allow it to run on a jailbroken phone.

Then, you use `ssh`, or `scp`, or something else to transfer it to your phone, where it should be installed under `/Applications/`.

You already have the best link on building iOS [Launch Daemons](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/).  I'd stick with that tutorial.  **No**, I don't have any open toolchain *template* in Xcode, either.  I just use Chris' tutorial to see how to build a non-graphical daemon `main` program (not a `UIApplication`), copy it to my `MyAppName.app` folder, and create a `com.mycompany.mydaemon.plist` file that defines the Launch Daemon.

Once the plist is installed in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` on the phone, you can start it, without having to reboot the phone, with:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.mydaemon.plist
```

at the command line (on the phone).  Or, just reboot the phone, and the daemon will start automatically.

Although I learned to do this before it was available, you can now look at [iOSOpenDev](http://iosopendev.com/) if you'd like a more polished way of doing some of this stuff.

Comment: Awesome explaination, i will try this and after reading your answer I am having a feeling that now I can do it.. Thanks alot

Comment: hey i tried this , but i am getting this error...Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'armv6'
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/JailbreakDemo/main.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/JailbreakDemo/VSAppDelegate.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/JailbreakDemo/VSViewController.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6   :(

Comment: I have installed iOSSDK4.2

Comment: Just one thing, where can i find MyAppName.app/ folder ??in my case  JailbreakDemo.app/ folder on my mac??

Comment: @iVishal, I assume you solved the first problem by looking [at this answer that I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13061562/119114).  Read about adding a **Build Rule** in your Xcode project settings.  On your second question, it depends: you can modify Xcode settings to configure **where** the build output goes, so it can be different on your Mac than on mine.  I believe the default is in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.  But, you can always just search for it:  `find / -name JailbreakDemo.app` and wait a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Xcode can be used for developing jailbreak-type projects. **Use [iOSOpenDev](http://iosopendev.com) to set up Xcode and iOS SDK** to allow jailbreak-type development.

iOSOpenDev comes with a set of templates, signs (with ldid) targets and creates Debian packages (packages are submitted to repos like ModMyI and BigBoss) during its build phase, in addition to installing packages directly to an iDevice with Cmd-Shift-I (build for profiling shortcut) for immediate testing, among other useful features for using Xcode to develop jailbreak-type projects.