# how to use ldid to install invalidly signed app

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing, jailbreak

I'm running Windows testing some iOS code from GitHub that other developers have been writing. Up until a few days ago I was using MacBuildServer to build the code and install the app. MacBuildServer had their enterprise cert revoked so now I can only build apps with invalid cert. I'm looking for a way to get this app to run on my jailbroken iPhone only.

How can I use `ldid` or similar to install and run an application signed with the invalid MacBuildServer enterprise license? Or how can I just build code and run it from my iPhone without using MacBuildServer?

I tried copying the .ipa over to my iPhone and running `ldid -S myApp.ipa` but that resulted in `_assert(0:Swap(mach_header_->magic) == MH_MAGIC)`. It appears `ldid` needs a .app but I don't know how to generate that.

When answering keep in mind I don't have a Mac available and getting a hold of Linux will take a decent amount of time so a Windows solution is preferred.

Comment: really why the minus one without an explanation? look around here and you will see that these types of questions are not discouraged. if you think i haven't put enough effort in to researching this feel free to let me know.

Comment: You can always run mac OSX virtually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign app **binary**; `ldid` is for signing application binaries. `ipa` is just a zip archive. Extract `.app` folder from it and sign application binary with `ldid`.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware that the `ipa` was a zip archive. I've now got this figured out using that information and the details from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768109/how-to-use-ldid (which I had already been aware of).

Comment: As a side note you can use `xcrun` to build an IPA once you have signed the application with `ldid`.

Comment: Also you'd need to have AppSync for iOS installed on your iDevice.